# Cannot Generate Map Atlas

Tags: qgis, atlas, atlas-generator, qgis-atlas

I am following a tutorial for using the map atlas feature in QGIS for the first time and I am encountering a problem. I believe I have everything specified I need to in order to generate an atlas, but for some reason I cannot preview or generate an atlas.

[image]

Here is my map and I want to generate an atlas for each of the red squares along the line I have generated. Below are my atlas settings.

[image]

Likewise here what it looks like when I hover over my atlas tab.

[image]

Any ideas as to why I cant generate an atlas from this information?

Comment: In your layout, did you setup the map1 property `Controlled by atlas`?